# Get Bookings from current date when using Date from - Date To

Tags: sql, date, datetime

**I have a table containing 4 columns**

column 1: BookingId - int

column 2: EventName - nvarchar(50)

column 3: Date_From - DateTime

column 4: Date_To - DateTime

now lets say it contains 50 records, and i want to display events that takes place on the current date. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Select * from BookingTable where Date_From >= getdate() AND  Date_To <= getDate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM < YOUR_TABLE >
WHERE cast(Date_From AS DATE) < = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
    AND cast(Date_To AS DATE) >= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

Comment: Umm, why? What issue do you foresee?

Comment: It wont show any data when i have 4 events happening on the current date

Comment: This would work if OP used `DATE` type instead of `DATETIME` type.

Comment: Oh yes, either you could change it to date format or you could trim of the time part away in the datetime fields and use it

Comment: And using `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` `DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is only true at 0:00

Comment: I've tried this, but this doesn't work either - select * from Booking WHERE Date_From >= Convert(date,GetDate()) AND Date_To <= Convert(date,GetDate())

Comment: `Date_From` and `Date_To` should be converted to date, `GetDate()` already is a date.

Comment: So how will the query look then?